# Rewriting expression involving power functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you please help me with the following equation from a pre-calculus course? As far as I know we can perform the division when the denominator and numerator have the same base (but could have different powers). But I see no way of achieving it here.

*For which a and b does the following hold (assume x>0 and y>0):*

$${\sqrt{\frac{(x^2y)^{-3}}{y^{-1}x}}} = x^ay^b$$

Comment: Inside the radical, use the product to a power rule for the numerator, then the quotient rule to simplify the radicand.

Comment: I still can't see that. In order to use quotient rule the denominator and numerator would have to be the same with the exception of the powers. How to do that exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several properties which you can use here:

$1$) $(rs)^t=r^ts^t$

Therefore $(x^2y)^{-3}=(x^2)^{-3}y^{-3}$

$2$) $(r^s)^t=r^{st}$

Therefore $(x^2)^{-3}y^{-3}=x^{-6}y^{-3}$

$3$) $st=ts$

Therefore $y^{-1}x=xy^{-1}$

$4$) $\dfrac{st}{uv}=\dfrac{s}{u}\cdot\dfrac{t}{v}$

Therefore $\dfrac{x^{-6}y^{-3}}{xy^{-1}}=\dfrac{x^{-6}}{x}\cdot\dfrac{y^{-3}}{y^{-1}}$

$5$) $\dfrac{x^m}{x^n}=x^{m-n}$

Therefore $\dfrac{x^{-6}}{x}\cdot\dfrac{y^{-3}}{y^{-1}}=x^{-7}y^{-2}$

$6$) If $s>0$ and $t>0$ then $\sqrt{st}=\sqrt{s}\sqrt{t}$

Therefore $\sqrt{x^{-7}y^{-2}}=\sqrt{x^{-7}}\sqrt{y^{-2}}$

$7$) If $s>0$ then $\sqrt{s^r}=s^{r/2}$

Therefore, $\sqrt{x^{-7}}\sqrt{y^{-2}}=x^{-7/2}y^{-1}$

So $a=-\dfrac{7}{2}$ and $b=-1$.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the 4th point/property!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
{\sqrt{\frac{(x^2y)^{-3}}{y^{-1}x}}} &= x^ay^b \\[3pt]
\frac{(x^2y)^{-3}}{y^{-1}x} &= x^{2a}y^{2b} \tag{$x,y>0$}\\[3pt]
(x^2y)^{-3} &= x^{2a+1}y^{2b-1} \\[3pt]
x^{-6}y^{-3} &= x^{2a+1}y^{2b-1} \\[3pt]
1 &= x^{2a+7}y^{2b+2} \\
\end{align}$$

If you need this to hold no matter what the values of $x>0$ and $y>0$ are, then

$$\begin{align}
2a+7 &= 0 \\[3pt]
a &= -\frac 72 \\[3pt]
2b+2 &=0 \\[3pt]
b &= -1 \\
\end{align}$$